# Helm template float arithmetic

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, go-templates

```
$ helm version
version.BuildInfo{Version:"v3.3.0", GitCommit:"8a4aeec08d67a7b84472007529e8097ec3742105", GitTreeState:"dirty", GoVersion:"go1.14.6"}
```

So I have my template:

```yaml
  minAvailable: {{ mul .Values.autoscaling.minReplicas 0.75 }}
```

values.yaml:

```yaml
autoscaling:
  minReplicas: 3
```

I would have expected a rendered output of `2.25`, but I get 0 (`3 * 0` because `0.75` gets floored...)

I've tried things like

```yaml
  minAvailable: {{ mul (float .Values.autoscaling.minReplicas) 0.75 }}
```

Ultimately I'm going to `floor` the value to get back to an int...

```yaml
  minAvailable: {{ floor ( mul .Values.autoscaling.minReplicas 0.75 ) }}
```

But I just don't understand why I can't seem to do simple float arithmetic

---

Other things I've tried

```yaml
  minAvailable: {{ float64 .Values.autoscaling.minReplicas }}
```

```yaml
  minAvailable: {{ float64 .Values.autoscaling.minReplicas | toString }}
```

nothing produces a float number....

I've even tried doing this in values.yaml

```
autoscaling:
  minReplicas: 3.0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pod Disruption Budgets actually take percentages...

so can do

```yaml
  minAvailable: "66%" # 2/3
```

or

```yaml
  minAvailable: "75%" # 3/4
```

From the docs:

> if you have 7 Pods and you set minAvailable to "50%", it's not immediately obvious whether that means 3 Pods or 4 Pods must be available. Kubernetes rounds up to the nearest integer, so in this case, 4 Pods must be available.

So essentially, `66%` of `3` is `1.98` so will be rounded up to `2`

Answer (score 13):

Helm and its templates support the default Go [text/template](https://pkg.go.dev/text/template?utm_source=godoc#hdr-Functions) functions and the function provided by the [Sprig](https://masterminds.github.io/sprig/) extension. Since Sprig version [3.2](https://github.com/Masterminds/sprig/releases/tag/v3.2.0) it also supports [Float Math Functions](https://masterminds.github.io/sprig/mathf.html) like `addf`, `subf`, `mulf`, `divf`, etc. In your case you would just need:

```
  minAvailable: {{ mulf .Values.autoscaling.minReplicas 0.75 }}
```

Answer (score 8):

These arithmetic functions aren't part of the core Go [text/template](https://godoc.org/text/template) language.  They come from a package of useful extensions called [Sprig](http://masterminds.github.io/sprig/) that Helm includes.  In particular, the documentation for its [Math Functions](http://masterminds.github.io/sprig/math.html) states at the top of the page

> All math functions operate on `int64` values unless specified otherwise.

Instead of trying to calculate floating-point `x * 0.75`, you could calculate integer `x * 3 / 4`.  Factor this as `(x * 3) / 4` and you can do this as reasonably precise integer arithmetic:

```yaml
minAvailable: {{ div (mul .Values.autoscaling.minReplicas 3) 4 }}
```

Comment: good answer that thanks!! I'm still going with the pdb percentages, because when the hpa scales up, the pdb applies to the minimum amount which means when the app is in full swing fired up 10 pods, then you can disrupt more than 75% of those